# How is this program still taking method copy in the stack even after the StackOverflowError?

Tags: java, exception, stack

If in the try block, the recursive calling of `main` method gives StackOverflowError then how is the copies of method test still being put on the stack?

```
class CatchError
{
    static void test()
    {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            main(null);
        }
        catch(Throwable ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Stack Overflow Error");
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                test();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the stack gets cleared when it catches the stackoverflow error?

Answer (score 3):

I ran your code and got

```
Stack Overflow ErrorStack Overflow ErrorStack Overflow ErrorStack Overflow ErrorStack Overflow ErrorStack Overflow ErrorStack Overflow ErrorStack Overflow ErrorStack Overflow Error
testStack Overflow Error
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
```

You can see that `StackOverflowError` (or to be exact, some `Throwable` which we can only assume is `StackOverflowError`, since you are catching `Throwable`) is caught multiple times before your `test` method is executed successfully.

This means the initial calls to `test` resulted in `StackOverflowError` being thrown by the catch block, which was caught by the catch block of the caller `main` method, which again tried to call `test`, which again threw `StackOverflowError`, and so on. Eventually enough of the stack frames occupied by the recursive calls to `main` were cleared, so you reached a catch clause that could actually execute the `test` method calls.